# Alternative source to Drozd's book on finite dimensional algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, books

I am trying to learn classic representation theory of finite dimensional algebras. My main source is the book "finite dimensional algebras" by Drozd and Kirichenko. I did not have too much trouble getting through the first two chapters but the third one on "the radical" of an algebra is a lot harder. I can hardly solve any of the exercises. Unfortunately, I do not have any specific questions about the material, it feels more like I am missing the big picture, the underlying idea of the theory. 
That's why I would like to consult another source to maybe find things presented in a similar fashion. Are there any books, lecture notes etc. that you can recommend?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The book of Assem, et al on Elements of Representation Theory Vol I is quite readable.

Comment: Another nice book is "Associative algebras" by R.S. Pierce (Springer, 1982).

Comment: And the book of Auslander, Reiten and Smalø completes the trinity.